# VBA excel- Create a folder in different locations based on if cell contains specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a button macro on excel that creates folders in different locations based on if the cell contains a specific text.
[Picture of excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjqW3.png)
In column C, I have all the folder names and if they contain "ABC" I want it to make a folder in U:\ABC test\ and if it has "CDE" then folder in U:\CDE test. This is what I have right now, which is just giving me the msg box "No Folder Created" and it is not creating any folders:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
 
Dim FldrName As String

On Error Resume Next

For i = 1 To 10
   FldrName = Cells(i, 3).Value
   If InStr(FldrName, "ABC") = 1 Then
   MkDir "U:\ABC test\" & FldrName
   ElseIf InStr(FldrName, "CDE") = 1 Then
   MkDir "U:\CDE test\" & FldrName
   Else
   MsgBox "No Folder Created"
   End If
Next i
 
End Sub
```

I am a bit new to VBA so any help would be appreciated!

edit- It works now thanks to Warcupine's comment but if I was constantly adding new folders weekly to column C, is there a way for the i= 1 thru 10 to automatically update to the latest row?

Comment: unless the ABC, CDE is the first thing in the name it won't return 1 so change `= 1` to `>= 1`. Also the first parameter in `Instr` is Start, so put a `1, ` before the `FldrName`

Comment: Thanks Warcupine! That worked! I also wanted to modify it by making the button automatically update to the newest row instead of just doing row 1 thru 10 if you know a way how to do this?

Comment: `lastrow = cells(rows.count, 3).end(xlup).row`

Comment: Got it, thanks so much!